# .htaccess how to not cache post requests

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using the following code to browser cache my static js files. Wordpress uses some get parameters for versioning e.g. file.js?ver=3.9.2

```
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "private, max-age=700000"
</filesMatch>
```

I was wondering whether were is a setting to not cache dynamically generated js files? E.g if it is a post request or a specific get request?

Comment: POST should already not cache by default. you can use cache-avoidance headers on requests that have the ver param to avoid wasting temporary client disk space.

Comment: Cache avoiding headers?

Comment: yeah, like Expires ( w/past date), Cache-Control (private, max-age=0, no-cache), Vary, Pragma, etc... see http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/ for info

Comment: maybe unclear. The wordpress ver is used for cache busting, so those files actually should be cached. Any other not.

Comment: sorry, do the opposite then; that link will show you how to insist on cache as well as avoid it...